# eclipse - svn synchronize - file differs only in line feed

Tags: eclipse, svn, synchronize

I'm working in a group where there are developers that use linux, windows and mac.
Often happens that in SVN repository text files have different text file line delimiters (CR / CRLF / LF).

Someone know if I could avoid to compare line delimiters during eclipse svn synchronize?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `svn:eol-style` propery on files, possibly even using automatic properties in svn (in linux that would usually be the [auto-props] section in ~/.subversion/config )